# WPF DataGrid, Copy to Clipboard after Ctrl+C,OnCopyingRowClipboardContent

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, clipboard

For WPF, Data Grid I am trying to copy to clipboard my custom text data, after `Ctrl+C`
Diverse attempts to use override
`OnCopyingRowClipboardContent(DataGridRowClipboardEventArgs args)` or `CopingRowClipboardContent event`, don't help.

Either clipboard gets empty or standard row text, but not what I would like to put there. 
For instance

```
protected override void OnCopyingRowClipboardContent(DataGridRowClipboardEventArgs args)
{
    Clipboard.SetText("Abc-hello");
    bool b1 = Clipboard.ContainsText();
    string s1 = Clipboard.GetText();
}
```

`s1` gets desired text, but after going out of this method clipboard gets empty.
Any idea if one can solve this?

Answer (score 17):

the correct way is add on XAML grid this property

```
ClipboardCopyMode="ExcludeHeader"
```

and for each property you want copy add this XAML

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn  ClipboardContentBinding="{Binding XXXXXX} .....
```

other facultative step  is implement the dataGrid event CopyingRowClipboardContent to modify the clipoard data

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the ClipboardRowContent property of DataGridRowClipboardEventArgs

```
static void dataGrid_CopyingRowClipboardContent(object sender, DataGridRowClipboardEventArgs e)
{
    e.ClipboardRowContent.Clear();
    e.ClipboardRowContent.Add(new DataGridClipboardCellContent(e.Item, (sender as DataGrid).Columns[0], "Abc-hello"));
}
```